# How to get column names from txt file into pandas data frame?

Tags: python

I have a txt file below with different column names, I want to extract all the column names without the data types etc. from the table into the pandas dataframe.

```
create table ad.TrackData
(
    track_id         int unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    ads_id           int                  null,
    ads_name         varchar(45)          null,
    play_time        timestamp            null,
    package_id       int                  null,
    package_name     varchar(45)          null,
    company_id       int                  null,
    company_name     varchar(45)          null,
    click_time       timestamp            null,
    demographic      varchar(300)         null,
    status           tinyint(1) default 0 null
);
```

I have no idea how I am supposed to do this, it would be very much appreciated if anyone could teach me some ways to perform this.

Comment: Can you share that text file as text instead image?

Comment: I have uploaded the text file as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you must save that text to `file.txt`. Then run a python script below:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
  txt = f.read()
  lines = txt.split('\n')
  columnNames = []
  for line in lines:
    if line.startswith('    '):
      columnNames.append(line.split('    ')[1])
  print(columnNames)
```

the output must be :

```
['track_id', 'ads_id', 'ads_name', 'play_time', 'package_id', 'package_name', 'company_id', 'company_name', 'click_time', 'demographic', 'status']
```